# Garbage collection takes long [How to debug what is being collected?]

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

I have an issue where the main javascript thread is being blocked due to garbage collection. (see screenshot below). The use case is that I am streaming JSON from a server with oboe.js, process some nodes, and put the nodes in a WebGl renderer and render those while they are streaming. This works pretty well, except for the garbage collector causing 2fps due to collecting blocks of 9mb which takes ~500ms.

The problem is that I do not know what is being collected and how I can prevent it from being collected. So my question is twofold:

- How to either reduce the size of blocks the garbage collector collects or postpone the moment that the garbage collector runs?
- How to debug what is being collected?

A snippet of what is happening:

[image: Performance Chart Chrome Dev Tools]

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue after all. There was a parsing process that spit out a variable that was a very complex nested object.

```
someModule.parse(someString, function(result){
    // result = complex deep nested object
    // process result
});
```

After the process result stage, the result variable was flagged for garbage collection, which it immediately did. I cached the result in a temporary variable and deleted it 'manually' later, which solved the problem.